# Not showing author, category and date on posts in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I've set up a Wordpress blog site. I've added the cateogory widget that comes with WP to the right sidebar and set it to show as a drop down. I need to change the layout of it (colours etc...) but can't seem to find what it's called, in which .php-file I need to look and if it's connected to any CSS-file. Can anyone help me? I think that others had run into this problem as well, but I can't seem to find any info about it...

/Em

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php function custom_taxonomy_dropdown( $taxonomy ) {
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
    if ( $terms ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    printf( '<li><a href="'.get_site_url().'/category/'.$term->slug.'">'.$term->name.' ('.$term->count.')</a></li>', esc_attr( $term->slug ), esc_html( $term->name ) );
        }
    }
}
?>
<?php custom_taxonomy_dropdown('category'); ?>
```